# Universal Google Analytics to Google Analytics 4 Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-analytics

I am using GoogleAnalytics in my Xamarin forms application using below link
https://github.com/KSemenenko/GoogleAnalyticsForXamarinForms.

above plugin is based on Universal GoogleAnalytics. Now I want to update Universal GoogleAnalytics to GoogleAnalytics 4 into my application.

I am tracking events as below in my code.

category, action, label

can I use above plugin for GA4.  if not is there any alternative for that?

do i need to change my code also for GA4 to track events and track views?

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: you can use the measurement protocol directly.   I have been working on an sdk for .net but as the measurement protocol is so limited its not going to be the same as what you could do with ua

Comment: Please indicate your platform/CMS every time you ask a question like that. Xamarin is a cross-platform open-source framework. And even though you link to a repo for implementation of Xamarin in apps, there's a chance you want it on your WP since app tracking hasn't been using the category action label model for a while now.